# Conditional DataTemplate returns object

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, itemscontrol, datatrigger

For a school project I require a selective template for a question object. Depending of its type I must show a different type (types are: open, multiple choice and closed)

I defined the template as followed

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Open" >
            <WrapPanel>
                <Label Content="Open"/>
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="multipleChoice" >
            <WrapPanel>
                <Label Content="multipleChoice"/>
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Closed" >
            <WrapPanel>
                <Label Content="Closed"/>
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

As you can see its now just contains a test label.
For showing I use an `ItemsControl` with setters. Based on another example shown here on StackOverflow. However this example returns a `System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies` for me and I don't know why. The commented code is working so the properties are reachable.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedInspection.Questionaire.Questions}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                    <ContentControl.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding type}" Value="Open">
                                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
                                            Value="{StaticResource Open}" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding type}" Value="multipleChoice">
                                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
                                            Value="{StaticResource multipleChoice}" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding type}" Value="Closed">
                                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
                                            Value="{StaticResource Closed}" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ContentControl.Style>
                </ContentControl>
            </DataTemplate>
            <!--
            <DataTemplate>
                <WrapPanel>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=QuestionContent}" />
                </WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
            -->
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

I'm binding to my question model which looks like this

```
public class Question 
{
    public Question() 
    {
        this.Answers = new ObservableCollection<Answer>(); 
    } 

    [Key] 
    public virtual int Id { get; set; } 
    public String QuestionContent { get; set; } 
    public string OpenAnswer { get; set; } 
    public string type { get; set; } 
    public virtual ObservableCollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; } 
    public virtual Questionaire Questionaire { get; set; } }
}
```

Am I do something wrong? How can I fix this?

Update: It's solved. The given example works correct. The given data by the database was incorrect which cause the error.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the code for the data object you are binding to?

Comment: I suspect the problem is with your DataContext, as `System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies` sounds like it's part of Entity Framework, and not a custom control you created.

Comment: Thats correct the questions are supplied by entity framework. but how is that an issue? and more important how can i work around that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is the `type` property set? And can you verify the values are what you expect it to be?

Based on the object model and your statement that the binding to `QuestionContent` works, then it looks like you have the DataContext hierarchy setup correctly, so the most likely problem cause is the data itself.

I also noticed you don't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the object model, so if it is set after the object is bound to then the UI won't know it needs to refresh.

Comment: 1/2 I'm binding to my question model which looks like this
`public class Question
    {
        public Question()
        {
            this.Answers = new ObservableCollection<Answer>();
        }
        [Key]
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }

        public String QuestionContent { get; set; }
        public string OpenAnswer { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public virtual ObservableCollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
        public virtual Questionaire Questionaire { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: 2/2 Is there anyway i can get a text field for open questions, radio for closed and checkbox for multipleChoice with the current format?

Comment: @IMarks Based on the object model and your statement that the binding to `QuestionContent` works, then it looks like you have the DataContext hierarchy setup correctly. How is the `type` property set? I notice you don't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the object model, so if it is set after the object is bound to then the UI won't know it needs to update. And as for your second question, I think the XAML you have now is fine. You are binding to a collection of objects, and using a `DataTrigger` to check a property and determine how to draw each object, which is how I would do it.

Comment: This is so weird... why would he need to use DataTemplates to switch out Labels based on a string?  This is X/Y territory.

Comment: It's temporary data (i don't want you to supply my whole school work, its meaned to learn me something xD). Thanks for watching into it @Rachel . Thanks to your description i found out the database was spilled with unconsistent data by the seed script where Open and Closed were often called open and closed (with lowercase). After fixing that it works.

Comment: @IMarks Good to hear! I've updated my answer based on the extra information you provided in comments in case anyone else has a similar problem or wants to know what the solution was :)

Answer (score 0):

DataTemplates are designed to be used with Types... as in `System.Type`.  They are easy ways to swap UI elements in and out that are designed to interact with a specific Type.  What you're doing is probably an abuse of this.  Here's why.

In order to use DataTemplates this way, you would have to refactor this (what I think you have)

```
enum TestType { open, multiplechoice, closed }
class Mahveurmerder // view model
{
    public TestType type {get;set;} 
    // snip
}
```

However, in order to use DataTemplates properly, you'd have to represent the test types as *actual types*.  Here's what I mean:

```
// describes a type of test
abstract class TestType { }
// implementations of this type
class OpenBookTest : TestType {}
class ClosedBookTest : TestType {}
class MultipleTypeTest : TestType {}
```

And you'd have to expose an instance of this type through a property of your view model

```
class Mahveurmerder
{
  public TestType type {get;set;}
}
```

And once you specify the data type on your templates:

```
<DataTemplate 
    xmlns:models="clr-namespace:ermagerdmerassinmernt.models"
    DataType="{x:Type OpenBookTest:}" >
    <WrapPanel>
        <Label Content="Open"/>
    </WrapPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

the ItemsControl will automatically pick them up (yes, it's that simple)

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedInspection.Questionaire.Questions}" />
```

Notice, that ItemsControl element is closed.  No data trigger BS crammed inbetween it and its closing tag.

**Now, of course, the *correct* way to do what you're trying to do** is to use an [IValueConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to convert `type` (I hope that's an enum in your application) to a string representation.  The implementation for this would be seven or eight lines and pretty bloody trivial.  You can find lots of examples here, so I'll leave that you to discover.

Then, all you'd need to do is

```
<!-- up in your window's or app's Resources -->
<converters:MerTestTyerpCernverter x:Name="Duh" />
```

and in your ItemsControl.ItemTemplate (get rid of all that other nonsense)

```
<Label Content="{Binding type, converter={StaticResource Duh}}"/>
```

WPF is pretty easy, once you understand the patterns.  If you're down a rabbit hole, stop and reconsider what you're doing--there's probably an easier way.

Comment: I'm using entity framework and type isn't a model/object but a property. Is there another way to use the given example because turning type into a object isn't possible within the remaining timespace due to the use of it within the rest of the app, which will cause a lot functionality to break. I know your example would be great as I have seen it before but I don't see a way to use it right now unless if there is a way to use a property instead of type to datatype.

Comment: @Will I'm not sure I understand why you think this is an abuse of DataTemplate. Why shouldn't we use DataTriggers to conditionally check a bound value and set a ContentTemplate to a different DataTemplate depending on value? I do it sometimes when needed.

Comment: @Rachel Considering what he probably needs (an IValueConverter) it is kind of an abuse.  Like trying to learn how to use a lathe to whittle sticks.

Comment: @IMarks you didn't read the last part--don't use DataTemplates, use an IValueConverter to convert the type to the approprate text representation.

Comment: @Will I guess if he was keeping the labels that would be solid advice, however since OP said he is using labels for testing right now, and based on the comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35020554/conditional-datatemplate-returns-object/35021201?noredirect=1#comment57771631_35022397), it sounds like different controls will be used to display the data later on, and they won't remain as a Label. In that case, I would definitely recommend using DataTemplates instead of trying to mess with converters.

Comment: @Rachel Oh, a nugget of gold buried under a... well, yeah.